# printf and std::cout behave differently trying to print out a structure member inside a std::vector obtained from an iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, printf, cout

I'm learning C++ iterators.
I had a weird bug when trying to get a member of a structure from an iterator, i was getting the wrong number.
After a lot of trial and error, I found out that it's the printf that prints out the wrong number when fed the structure member.

This code gives the correct result:

```
int n_payload = cl_custom_iterator.get_payload();
std::cout << "get_payload: " << n_payload << "\n";
```

This code gives the wrong result:

```
int n_payload = cl_custom_iterator.get_payload();
My_class::Node st_node = cl_custom_iterator.get_node();
printf("%p | get_payload: %d | get_node.n_payload: %d\n", cl_custom_iterator, n_payload, st_node.n_payload);
```

This is the minimal example that replicates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

class My_class
{
    public:
        //Troublemaker?
        struct Node
        {
            int n_payload;
        };
        //Constructor
        My_class(void)
        {
            Node st_node;
            for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 5; cnt++)
            {
                st_node.n_payload = 33+cnt;
                gast_my_array.push_back( st_node );
                std::cout << "Push " << cnt << " | Payload: " << gast_my_array[cnt].n_payload << "\n";
            }
        }

        template <typename T>
        class iterator
        {
            public:
                //! @brief constructor for the custom iterator
                iterator(std::vector<T>& ira_parent_vector, size_t in_starting_index = 0) :
                    gra_vector(ira_parent_vector),
                    gu32_index(in_starting_index)
                {
                    //Do nothing
                    return;
                }
                iterator<T>& operator++()
                {
                    gu32_index++;
                    return *this;
                }
                iterator<T> operator++(int)
                {
                    iterator<T> tmp(*this);
                    gu32_index++;
                    return tmp;
                }
                T &operator &(void)
                {
                    return &gra_vector[gu32_index];
                }
                int get_payload( void )
                {
                    return gra_vector[gu32_index].n_payload;
                }
                T get_node( void )
                {
                    return gra_vector[gu32_index];
                }
                bool operator==(const iterator<T>& icl_rhs_iterator) const
                {
                    return gu32_index == icl_rhs_iterator.gu32_index;
                }
                bool operator!=(const iterator<T>& icl_rhs_iterator) const
                {
                    return gu32_index != icl_rhs_iterator.gu32_index;
                }

            private:
                std::vector<T>& gra_vector;
                size_t gu32_index;
        };

        iterator<Node> begin()
        {
            return iterator<Node>(gast_my_array, 0);
        }
        iterator<Node> end()
        {
            return iterator<Node>(gast_my_array, gast_my_array.size());
        }
    private:
        std::vector<Node> gast_my_array;
};

int main(void)
{
    My_class my_class_instance;

    for (My_class::iterator<My_class::Node> cl_custom_iterator=my_class_instance.begin();cl_custom_iterator!=my_class_instance.end();cl_custom_iterator++)
    {
        int n_payload = cl_custom_iterator.get_payload();
        My_class::Node st_node = cl_custom_iterator.get_node();
        //std::cout << "get_payload: " << cl_custom_iterator.get_payload();
        std::cout << "get_payload: " << n_payload << "\n";
        printf("%p | get_payload: %d | get_node.n_payload: %d\n", cl_custom_iterator, n_payload, st_node.n_payload);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I am getting on my machine compiled with mingw -std=c++11

get_payload fed to std::cout and manually extracting the structure member from the node give the correct result 33, 34, ...

get_payload fed to printf prints out the wrong number 1, 2, ...

```
Push 1 | Payload: 34
Push 2 | Payload: 35
Push 3 | Payload: 36
Push 4 | Payload: 37
get_payload: 33
006efec8 | get_payload: 0 | get_node.n_payload: 33
get_payload: 34
006efec8 | get_payload: 1 | get_node.n_payload: 34
get_payload: 35
006efec8 | get_payload: 2 | get_node.n_payload: 35
get_payload: 36
006efec8 | get_payload: 3 | get_node.n_payload: 36
get_payload: 37
006efec8 | get_payload: 4 | get_node.n_payload: 37

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.141 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

---

**Fixed Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class My_class
{
    public:
        struct Node
        {
            int n_payload;
        };
        //Constructor with example
        My_class()
        {
            Node st_node;
            for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 5; cnt++)
            {
                st_node.n_payload = 33+cnt;
                gast_my_array.push_back( st_node );
                std::cout << "Push " << cnt << " | Payload: " << gast_my_array[cnt].n_payload << "\n";
            }
        }
        //iterator
        template <typename T>
        class iterator
        {
            public:
                //! @brief constructor for the custom iterator
                iterator(std::vector<T>& ira_parent_vector, size_t in_starting_index = 0) :
                    gra_vector(ira_parent_vector),
                    gu32_index(in_starting_index)
                {
                    //Do nothing
                    return;
                }
                iterator<T>& operator++()
                {
                    gu32_index++;
                    return *this;
                }
                iterator<T> operator++(int)
                {
                    iterator<T> tmp(*this);
                    gu32_index++;
                    return tmp;
                }
                //FIX: I overload the * operator to get a reference to the element of std::vector of which I can easily get the address and content
                T &operator *()
                {
                    return gra_vector[gu32_index];
                }
                bool operator==(const iterator<T>& icl_rhs_iterator) const
                {
                    return gu32_index == icl_rhs_iterator.gu32_index;
                }
                bool operator!=(const iterator<T>& icl_rhs_iterator) const
                {
                    return gu32_index != icl_rhs_iterator.gu32_index;
                }

            private:
                std::vector<T>& gra_vector;
                size_t gu32_index;
        };
        iterator<Node> begin()
        {
            return iterator<Node>(gast_my_array, 0);
        }
        iterator<Node> end()
        {
            return iterator<Node>(gast_my_array, gast_my_array.size());
        }
    private:
        std::vector<Node> gast_my_array;
};

int main(void)
{
    My_class my_class_instance;

    for (My_class::iterator<My_class::Node> cl_custom_iterator=my_class_instance.begin();cl_custom_iterator!=my_class_instance.end();cl_custom_iterator++)
    {
        //FIX: printf has undefined behaviour with %p of an object. std::cout of the address of a reference will print out the address
        std::cout << "iterator address: " << &*cl_custom_iterator << " | payload: " << (*cl_custom_iterator).n_payload << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output (correct):

```
Push 0 | Payload: 33
Push 1 | Payload: 34
Push 2 | Payload: 35
Push 3 | Payload: 36
Push 4 | Payload: 37
iterator address: 0x711720 | payload: 33
iterator address: 0x711724 | payload: 34
iterator address: 0x711728 | payload: 35
iterator address: 0x71172c | payload: 36
iterator address: 0x711730 | payload: 37

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.109 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Does the code with `printf` really build? `cl_custom_iterator` is not a pointer, it's a C++ object that the old C function `printf` knows nothing about. Attempting to print the objects value using the `%p` format leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The compiler gives me a warning when using %p on a class object, but it's pretty happy compiling and linking everything. 

I removed the %p and the printf now output the correct number, you are right.

I use printf %p because I find it quick way to get the addresses and learn what's going on under the hood, shallow copies, hard copies, references and whatnot. This is the first time I saw %p causing the printf to actually malfunction.

Comment: Please listen to the compiler, it knows what it talks about. To print the address of something using `printf` and `%p` you first of all must make sure you have an actual pointer, second make sure that it's a `void*` pointer. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to UB. Or better yet, don't use the type-unsafe `printf` function at all in your C++ code.

Comment: I hear you, I'm learning C++ and trying to unlearn the bad habits I had with C.
Do you have some suggestions on how to print out the address of an object?

Comment: Assuming that you want to print the address of the object that the iterator "points" to, then dereference the iterator to get a reference to the object and then use the pointer-to operator `&` to get a pointer to the object. Like `&*cl_custom_iterator`. And you can use it as-is with `std::cout` like `std::cout << &*cl_custom_iterator << " | get_payload: " << n_payload << " | get_node.n_payload: " << st_node.n_payload << '\n';`

Comment: The compiler get confused `error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'My_class::iterator<My_class::Node>')|` my iterator overloads the * operator to get the content (Node structure) when scanning the iterator. I could build a special method to give me a string with the address inside from `this` from inside the class, but it feels like a boilerplate.

Comment: Oh, your iterator doesn't have an overloaded `*` operator as is customary. Or an overloaded `->` operator. Instead it have an overloaded pointer-to operator `T &operator &(void)` which returns a pointer (correctly) but the return-type is wrong. It should be `T*`. If you fix the return type then you can use `&cl_custom_iterator` to get a pointer to the `Node` object. However, overloading this pointer-to operator is very uncommon.

Comment: `operator &` should be `operator *`, and `return &gra_vector[gu32_index];` should be `return gra_vector[gu32_index];`

Comment: @molbdnilo this is the only combination that works!
`T &operator *(void) { return gra_vector[gu32_index]; }
std::cout << "iterator address: " << &*cl_custom_iterator << "\n";
iterator address: 0x10a1720`
All other combinations, even removing the overload, the compiler gets confused an cannot resolve the address as a text.

Comment: Yes, that is as expected. (Drop the `(void)` parameter habit and write `()`. They are equivalent in C++.)

Comment: @molbdnilo if you post it as answer I can accept that. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: No the compiler is not "happy". It gives you a warning. Treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: I think it's a fool's errand to have no warnings. Different compilers will be confused/unhappy about different things. I remember code that gave no warnings on mingw but didn't even compile on the visual studio compilers. I use GCC because it has a more consistent behaviour when targeting X64 on windows and X64 on linux.

Comment: Look, you got a warning that you *did not understand*, failed to treat as an error, and got bitten by it. If I were you I would refrain from telling people they are fools for having a no-warning policy for *at least* a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C functions like `printf` know nothing about C++ types like iterators and this only compiles because `printf` is variadic function and therefore there is no type checking of it's arguments.

You could try this instead

```
printf("%p | get_payload: %d | get_node.n_payload: %d\n", 
    &*cl_custom_iterator, n_payload, st_node.n_payload);
```

using `&*cl_custom_iterator` should ensure that the argument is a pointer, as required by the `%p` format specifier.

Although looking at your `iterator` class I'm not sure that is going to compile.

Comment: I get: `error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'My_class::iterator<My_class::Node>')|` I find always fiddly to try and get a printable address for an object, it's why I default to %p. Do you know how to do it? I don't really care about printf, I'm happy using std::cout.

Comment: @05032MendicantBias Yes that's what I suspected. Your iterator should define `operator*` (which returns a reference to the item the iterator is referring to). Without an `operator*` you class is not a true iterator. It should also define `operator->` which returns a pointer to the item being referred to.

Comment: @05032MendicantBias Once you have `operator*` defined and returning a reference, then the `&*` trick will work.

Comment: @05032MendicantBias I am assuming that you want the address of the item the iterator is referring to, if you what the address of the iterator itself, then that is just `&cl_custom_iterator`. But you would have to remove the current `operator&`, which is very strange. It's rare to define `operator&`. Maybe you need to revise how iterators work.